# In a lot of JSP/Servlet app examples, why is the .inc extension used instead of .jsp for include?

Tags: java, jsp, jspinclude

In a lot of JSP/Servlet app examples that I saw, when the app includes a resource in a JSP through the directive or action include, then the file included had an `.inc` extension. Why is that? Why we do not use a `.jsp` extension instead?

Comment: If extension is not jsp then <jsp:include/> consider that page as **static** resource. If that resource is dynamic then it acts on a request and sends back a result.

Answer (score 6):

`.inc` is short for *include*. A `jsp` extension would imply that the file was a complete page; using an `inc` extension makes it clear that the file isn't intended to stand alone.